# Capture and cancel angularJS $destroy event based on window.confirm() choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I have a form, and I set an event listener on it that looks like this

```
setExitCheck = () => {
    this.$scope.$on('$destroy', (e) => {
        if ($('#compForm').hasClass('ng-dirty')) {
            if (window.confirm('You may have unsaved changes! Press ok to continue, or press cancel to go back and save your work.') === false) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The idea is that if the form is dirty and has the `ng-dirty` class, and the user tries to initiate a stateChange and the `$destroy` event is called; give them the opportunity to stay on the page to save their changes, or press okay and move ahead with their stateChange at the cost of losing their work.

The eventListener goes off just fine, the if statement recognizes correctly when `Ok` or `Cancel` is pressed. The problem is, `e.preventDefault` doesn't seem to stop the $destroy cycle, or the stateChange from happening.

How do I prevent the $destroy cycle from occurring? Am I going about this the wrong way maybe?

Comment: You could hook into the state change, and prevent that from happening, instead of preventing the component from being destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found came thanks to Jeff Huijsmans who recommended initially to capture the state change instead of the $destroy event. His advice set down the proper train of thought to generate a solution that worked for me.

`$stateChangeStart` has been deprecated in the latest version of angular router, and I ended up having to use their `$transitions` api.

The code now looks like this and works as intended *****

```
setExitCheck = () => {
    this.$transitions.onStart({}, () => {
        if ($('#compForm').hasClass('ng-dirty')) {
            if (window.confirm('You may have unsaved changes! Press ok to continue, or press cancel to go back and save your work.') === false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    $('#compForm').areYouSure();
};
```

Notice the one line at the bottom of the method the `$().areYouSure();`

The $transitions api checks for just that, transitions inside the app where the document is never unloaded. Due to this the $transitions api did not look for unload events.

Rather than write more code to account for unloads, and form checking, etc. I implemented a very straightforward 3rd part library that handles unload checks for me.

[jquery.are-you-sure](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure) is a great, light-weight form checker, and onbeforeunload event handler that is very simple to use in my controller as you can see from my code.

**In summary** the angular router `$transitions` API is monitoring the DOM for a change in transition where a unload event does **NOT** occur. And the jquery.are-you-sure library is monitoring the DOM for an event where the DOM **IS** unloaded, such as navigating to a entirely new domain, or closing the browser tab/window.

***** I recognize it is better practice to access my form's `$isDirty` value via `$scope` but I was having issues finding access to it. I think it has to do with the general set up of the application and its use of TypeScript, and typings files. I'm not sure to be honest. But this code is working wonderfully, so it is what I have decided to run with.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand if a form is dirty you can just access it through the `$scope.formName` and access the `$dirty` property of that object.
Even if your code works fine because of the class, it's actually a bad practice and the $dirty should be used.
By the way, why you don't bind an event to the `window.onblur` and/or `window.onbeforeunload` property?
In the way you executed, the code is executed when the $destroy has been called, so the destroying already started. 
I think you should change your logic using those other events instead.

You can try to stop the propagation of the $destroy accessing the $event and using this code:

`$event.stopPropagation();`

But I still recommend you to use the other events, even if it will work.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with window.onblur, but I'll look into implementing it. window.onbeforeunload does not work because Angular is manipulating the DOM to change the page, while not navigating away from the current document. That is what lead me to attempt to catch the $destroy event.

Comment: If you are navigating out from the page but inside your app, you just have to intercept your statachange events. It s much easier.

Comment: I understood that you meant leaving the page so your application. The state change event so it's the answer to your question